# Difference between Hard and Soft keywords in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

What is the main difference between Hard and Soft Keywords in Kotlin. How are these different from java programming languages.

Comment: Please first you search on your browser. Refer: https://beginnersbook.com/2017/12/kotlin-keywords-identifiers/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hard keywords** in Kotlin behave same as the keywords in java and have the same rules, like hard keywords cannot be used as identifier.

**For example**

you cannot do

`var false = null`

or

`var continue = null`

As these keywords are already reserved for predefined meaning and cannot be used in any other meaning

**Soft keyword:-**

Kotlin introduce a concept of context dependent keywords that called **Soft Keywords**

these keyword can be used as keywords in the context when they are applicable and can be used as identifiers too in other context

**for example**

you can use keyword `import` outside the class to import the packages into your source file
but also inside the class you can define import as identifier

`var import = null`

or

`var import = "test"`

below is the reference of the official documentation of kotlin, where you can find the list of all soft and hard keywords
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/keyword-reference.html